# Can I create an Ad-Hoc network between NAT virtual machines and computers/virtual-machines external to host?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I want to create a network between virtual machines on my laptop which are running Windows Server and other virtual machines in another laptop that will be running Windows Server as well without using a router. Is this possible and can I do it using the NAT option for the VM's network adapter or do I have to use the bridged option? Any hints on how to do this?

I'm using VMware Workstation.

Comment: `I'm using VMware` - VMware what? VMware is a company, not a product.

Comment: VMware workstation* it was in the tags

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer: Yes, don't use NAT.

Grab a crossover cable, connect the two laptops with the cross over. Setup the network interface cards on the laptops to have static IP addresses on a shared subnet.

Change the network type in vmware to bridged mode and bridge on the ethernet adapter.

You can't use NAT because NAT creates an "internal" network on each laptop that the other cannot see.